# Regex Words and Spaces Only starting from a position in the string

Tags: regex, string

I am tring to extract from a string only words and spaces (exclude numbers) AND do this starting from a position in the string

Example string (minus the double quotes)

```
"             1        Job 3216547 asldkjasflkj alskjdalksjd lkjasdlkajs dlkajsdlkajs jkasdlkja "
```

Expected outcome

```
Job  asldkjasflkj alskjdalksjd lkjasdlkajs dlkajsdlkajs jkasdlkja
```

I don't mind having that double space between the word job and the next

The following pretty much gets me what I want but it includes the spaces before the word Job

```
[^\d]
```

Any body know how to achieve this?

Comment: `([^\d\s]+)` https://regex101.com/r/5I5HdW/1

Comment: Thanks, @CodeDifferent but that strips the spaces out from between the words as well. I still need the spaces between the words, just not the spaces at the front of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `[A-Za-z]+\s`
This will just give you letters and one space.